# Is it possible to send email just to one person but in the TO field to add more email addresses(these users should not get an email)?

Tags: email, email-headers

What I am trying to do is, sending an email to one person but I want to add more email addresses in the TO field and don't want that users to get the email. Is it possible to somehow configure this?

Comment: _and don't want that users to get the email_ Why should they be in the TO section at all?

Comment: to know that some other users got the same email but of course with different content.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve.. sounds like magic to me..

Comment: An email is an email.  If you want to let person A know that person B got an email with different contents at the same time, _put it in the email body_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible. SMTP doesn't actually use the headers for anything; the envelope recipient list controls who actually receives a message (though many user-visible email programs will simply copy the `To:`, `Cc:`, and `Bcc:` headers into the envelope on submission).

Because you are not asking about any particular language, I won't post code which probably won't be useful to you anyway. In pseudocode, something like

```
s = smtp.connect(server)
s.ehlo()
s.from(envelope.sender)
for r in envelope.recipients:
    s.rcpt(r)
s.data('''From: me@example.net
To: you@example.org
Subject: SMTP doesn't care

By the time SMTP transmits the actual message,
the recipient information has already been sent 
separately.''')
```